# Subsetting a dataframe using column sum in Python

Tags: r, python-2.7, subset, column-sum

I have a sparse data frame with more than 500 columns. I want to remove the columns having sum of entries less than a threshold value say 100. How can I do this in Python?

In R I can achieve this using:

```
df2 <- df51[,colSums(df51) >= 100]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, that translates to

```
df2 = df1.drop(df1.columns[df1.sum() >= 100], axis=1)
```

The axis=1 option is for dropping columns while axis=0 is for rows.